# How do I define select option values in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

...while maintaining model bindings?

I have a select menu like so:

`<select class="form-control" ng-model="activeTask" ng-options="task.title for task in tasks"> </select>`

That populates some text like so:

`<span>{{activeTask.title}}</span>`

The `Projects` resource grabs some json here (which is working fine):

```
function TimerCtrl($scope, Projects) {
    $scope.projects = Projects.get({}, {isArray:true}, function(projects) {
        $scope.tasks = $scope.projects[0].tasks;
        $scope.activeProject = $scope.projects[0];
        $scope.activeTask = $scope.tasks[0];
    });
}
```

This is the `Projects` service (which is working fine as well):

```
angular.module('projectServices', ['ngResource']).
factory('Projects', function($resource) {
    return $resource('data/projects.json', {}, {
        get: {method:'GET', isArray:true}
    });
});
```

and this is the JSON (which is also fine):

```
[
    {
        "title":"Chores",
        "url_title":"chores",
        "category":"Home",
        "tasks": [
            {"title":"Cleaning", "url_title":"cleaning"},
            {"title":"Yard Work", "url_title":"yard_work"},
            {"title":"Walking the Dogs", "url_title":"url_title"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "title":"Personal Website",
        "url_title":"personal_website",
        "category":"Work",
        "tasks": [
            {"title":"Design", "url_title":"design"},
            {"title":"Front End Dev", "url_title":"front_end_dev"},
            {"title":"Node Dev", "url_title":"node_dev"},
            {"title":"PHP Dev", "url_title":"php_dev"}
        ]
    }
]
```

Everything works fine with the numeric values that Angular automatically creates.
My problem is...the values need to be the url-friendly string `task.url_title` but the option text should be `task.title`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I want to go drink a beer!

**So, here's the solution I went with:**

I used the `task` object itself as the value like so:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="activeTask" ng-options="task as task.title for task in tasks">
```

This allowed me to easily bind the span value to display the task `title`, not `url_title`:

```
<span>{{activeTask.title}}</span>
```

Thanks to @sza for his pointing me in the right direction. His suggestions are in the comments of the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the comprehension expression to

```
ng-options="task.url_title as task.title for task in tasks"
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/P26ax/)**</kbd>

Comment: I tried this previously (while reviewing the api docs) but the output does not change. It still shows the automatically generated integers as the value.

Comment: @Jbird Added a working demo for you. If you can't figure it out, then it got be something else.

Comment: Angular is keeping track of the value but the actual value attribute still shows up as integers in your example. This is currently how the app is behaving. Also, the second challenge I mentioned is that I need the span to display the title, not the url_title.

Comment: @Jbird I have explained that many times in this site. That value doesn't matter. AngularJS manages the value in its self-contained scope. So what really matters is the model variable rather than the actually value in the html.

Comment: In this case, it does matter because I need those values submitted with the form and it seems like overkill to create some contrived means of grabbing those values from the model before submitting the form when the values should already be in the form's serialized data. So, is there no way of populating the actual attribute?

Comment: @Jbird Since you use AngularJS, why not just use it in proper way? AngularJS's self-contained scope encapsulated all the hassles for you and you should not worry about anything relating to HTML binding. It just works if you access any model from the scope. Does it make sense?

Comment: +1  Don't fight Angular here.  Do it the Angular way.  You will be rewarded.

Comment: Do you see any problems with using the task object itself as the model value? `<select class="form-control" ng-model="activeTask" ng-options="task as task.title for task in tasks">`? That allows me to bind the span to `activeTask.title` like so `<span ng-bind="activeTask.title"></span>` because I need the span to display the `title` not the `url_title`

Comment: @sza I marked your answer as correct since you pointed me in the right direction. I updated my question with the complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ng-options="..."`. Also use `ng-model="..."` or otherwise it won't work.

Here's the breakdown of it:

```
<select ng-options="ITEM.VALUE as ITEM.LABEL for ITEM in ITEMS" ng-model="val">
  <option>placeholder value which goes at the top of the element</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried this previously (while reviewing the api docs) but the output does not change. It still shows the automatically generated integers as the value.